# How do I get ->getAttribute('class') converted to a string to be used for comparison using STRPOS in PHP

Tags: php

Using

```
    $html = file_get_contents("$fileName");
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument; $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $test = $xpath->query('//div');
```

and a FOREACH LOOP

I am able to get the div class using

```
$divClass = $div->getAttribute('class');
echoing $divClass will display 'class='suchNsuch"'
```

But when I try to compare it as follows I do not get a result.

```
if (strpos( $divClass, "suchNsuch")) {
    echo $divClass // Nothing happens
}
```

I need to use strpos because the class may be 'class='suchNsuchNsoOn"'
I have tried getAttributeNodeValue, getAttributeNS and various others with no luck and YES it must be done in PHP
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strpos() returns the position of the match or false if not found.  The way you wrote the condition 0 is evaluated as false.  Try this instead:

```
if(strpos(...) !== false) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: All day long and didn't see it. Thank you for the eyes!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're doing, but it appears you're comparing the string `"class='suchNsuch'"` with the string `"suchNsuch"` will fail for obvious reasons (... they're different).

You could extract the value you need with a regex, I suppose:

```php
$stringForComparison = '';
$found = preg_match('/class="(.*)"/', $divClass, $result);
if ($found) {
  $stringForComparison = $result[1];
}
```

Also, [`strpos` returns an integrer value or false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), which might be "falsy" (i.e. `0`), so you should check for

```
strpos() !== false
```